# File Attachment with Xamarin.Essentials

Tags: xamarin.forms, email-attachments

Using Xamarin Essentials Email class, I can open the default email application this way

```
public async Task SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> recipients)
{
    try
    {
        var message = new EmailMessage
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            To = recipients,
            //Cc = ccRecipients,
            //Bcc = bccRecipients
        };
        await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fbsEx)
    {
        // Email is not supported on this device
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some other exception occurred
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to attach a file in the code? I'm not finding any option in the api.

Comment: I think that is impossible with the Essentials plugin, you would have to do your own implementation or just let the users attach files on the email when the app launch email default application.

Comment: Essentials plugin does not have the api for Email attachment yet. But you can implement it using C#.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I decided to follow the suggestion of FabriBertani and let the user attach the file with the default email application.

Comment: It is possible with the Xamarin.Essentials version 1.1.0. Please take a look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var message = new EmailMessage
{
    Subject = "Hello",
    Body = "World",
};
var fn = "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

message.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file));
await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
```